# executing multiple .exe files serially through batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, exe

I have three .exe files inside a folder and I want to run them serially one after another through a batch file. That means, 2nd .exe file will execute after the operation of 1st .exe file. I have written a file but when I run it, the are not executing serially. My batch file is:

```
Start ""  ".\a.exe"
Start ""  ".\b.exe"
Start ""  ".\c.exe"
```

How will I execute these files one after another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `start` if you need to wait until the execution of the exe to execute the next one. `start` will create a new process and return to the next statement without waiting.

Just use the exe as it is without the `start`.

So your batch file should be like.

```
.\a.exe
.\b.exe
.\c.exe
```

Comment: It will only wait if the EXE is marked as a Console app... if it's marked as a GUI app it won't wait unless you do `start /wait guiapp.exe`.

Comment: Will I write in this way? Start " "  ".\a.exe"
 " "  ".\b.exe"
 " "  ".\c.exe"  @Karthikeyan Vaithilingam

Comment: @user3114849 Updated my answer.

Comment: @TripeHound: that's only true on the command line.  The batch interpreter always waits regardless of whether it is a GUI or a console executable.

Comment: @HarryJohnston A quick test with `notepad` shows you are right, but I could have sworn I've seen the launch-and-forget behaviour in the past even from batch files, hence the need for `start /wait`. Unless it was all a dream...

Comment: @TripeHound: well, some applications launch child processes (or pass a command to an existing process) and then exit.  But `start /wait` won't help in that case.

Comment: `start/w .\a.exe` <br> `start/w .\b.exe` <br> `start/w .\c.exe`